# Why does img tag without src take height in IE11?

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I soon discovered that if an `img` tag with `100%` width is given no `src` then it takes a lot of height in IE11. E.g. test the following in IE11 and chrome:

```html
<img src="" alt="" style="width: 100%;">
<p>Test text loren is the ipsum</p>
```

Is it a but in IE11 or is the right way and all other browsers are wrong?

Comment: It's just the basic behaviour of the browser with which it handles different scenarios. Varies browser to browser like you have noticed.

Comment: `src` is a mandatory attribute for the `img` tag. I don't think you can make any assumptions about how it will behave without one.

Comment: @Turnip There was some issue from the backend on a website. `src`'s value came from the backend and for some reason it was empty on one of the pages. And we did not notice the problem because we use IE rarely.

Comment: In that case using javascript or JQuery why don't you give a default value to the all images `src` attribute which do not have any(or an empty value).

Comment: I had the same issue when lazy loading images for a carousel component. The carousel had more height in IE until all images had been shown.. What fixed it for me was setting the height of the image to 0 until it had been loaded.